# Pandas value_counts() + weight

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [121, 34324, 111, 12, 45, 232],
              'weight': [10, 2, 80, 49, 71, 18],
              'var_bool': [True, True, False, True, False, True],
              'var_cat': ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'blue']})

df['var_bool'] = df['var_bool'].astype('bool')
df['var_cat'] = df['var_cat'].astype(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype())
```

I'd like to apply a function to count the frequency of unique labels, with a weight given by the "weight" column:

```
df['var_bool'].value_counts() #I need to consider the weight of each row
df['var_cat'].value_counts() #I need to consider the weight of each row
```

The function has to work both for "var_bool" and "var_cat", possibly with a fast engine (the dataframe is quite big). Thanks a lot!

edit: the result should be:

```
#for "var_bool"
True 79
False 151

#for "var_cat"
red 90
blue 20
green 120
```

Comment: No, for the first row I want to count "True" 10 times (not 1), so on for the other columns. Thanks

Comment: could you check my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this can be done without groupby.

```
df.groupby('var_bool')['weight'].sum()
```